# Getting the error that Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new in react js and i am following the Udemy course but I am getting the error that "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions".Basically I am using a firebase database to develop this application in this app user put their name as a student.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

var firebase=require('firebase');
var uuid=require('uuid');

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAwXf9-4PgY0ttsGy1FHmyLHZOFO1oVcic",
    authDomain: "uservey-206d4.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://uservey-206d4.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "uservey-206d4",
    storageBucket: "uservey-206d4.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "723372497898",
    appId: "1:723372497898:web:0ebb13dcb9ce6d2f6eb093",
    measurementId: "G-J6190VVVQH"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class Survey extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            uid:uuid.v1(),
            studentName:'',
            answers:{
                answer1:'',
                answer2:'',
                answer3:'',
            },
            isSubmitted:false
         };
    }
    render() {
       var studentName;
       var questions;
         if(this.state.studentName ==='' && this.state.isSubmitted === false){
          <div>
              <h1>Please Enter Your Name:</h1>
             <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"/>
              </div>
         }
        return( 
        <div>
            {studentName}
            ------------------------------
            {questions}
            </div> );}
}

export default Survey;
```

Comment: Could you specific which line the error is related?

Answer (score 0):

render function expects you to return jsx to render, so:

```js
 render() {
   if(this.state.studentName ==='' && this.state.isSubmitted === false){
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>Please Enter Your Name:</h1>
         <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"/>
       </div>
    )
   }

   return ( 
     <div>
            {studentName}
            ------------------------------
            {questions}
     </div>
   );
}
```

also, fix your indents, it helps to keep your sanity in the long run